# How to properly format if statement with html and php

Tags: formatting

I have an if statement that has some html and php in it. The way I have formatted it at them moment seems a bit messy:

**EDIT**

```
    <?php

         $audio_source = get_field( 'audio_source' );

         if ( $audio_source == 'From Url' ) {

             $audio = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'audio_post_format_url', true );
             echo wp_oembed_get( $audio );

         } elseif ( $audio_source == 'From Library' ) {

             if ( !empty( get_field( 'audio_post_format_library' ) ) ) {
                 $audio = get_field( 'audio_post_format_library', $post->ID ); ?>
                 <audio controls class="audio-player">
                     <source src="<?php echo $audio['url']; ?>" type="audio/mpeg">
                 </audio>
              <?php
             }
         }
              ?>
```

Just wondering how I could make this cleaner in terms of readability and what is the most appropriate way to format this code. I know I should use the following approach when I have php and html together:

```
<?php if ( !empty( get_field( 'audio_post_format_library' ) ) ) : ?>
    <audio controls class="audio-player">
        <source src="<?php echo $audio['url']; ?>" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But on this specific case I am a bit confused on what to use.

Comment: Think about the purpose of the opening and closing PHP tags. These are for "escaping HTML".  In a string of PHP statements, there is no reason to open and close, open and close, etc.   From your `elseif` thru your nested `if` statement is all PHP.  No need to `<?php ?>` again and again.  It is also recommended to only use one syntax style but you are mixing the use of curly braces and the alt colon syntax.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Please have a look at my edit above to see if that's what you mean and if it is the best way to format it.

Comment: Much cleaner.    You might find this very helpful as well.  https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/.  Personally, I didn't realize the alt PHP syntax was taboo these days until I scanned this.